# Seoul JSA tour dates

Tags: south-korea, seoul, north-korea

We are looking for a JSA tour on the 4th or 5th July but nowhere seems to have availability. Is the JSA closed on these days or are all the tours just booked? Need to know so I know if I should keep looking!

Many thanks.

Comment: What's a JSA tour?

Answer (score 1):

I have now had confirmation that the week commencing July 3rd is a military training week and therefore the JSA is closed.